# Reset a variable if input changes value

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like this function to reset the counter every time there's a change in the text input

This is my current JavaScript code:

```js
let counter = 0

const button = document.getElementById('updatePic')
button.addEventListener('click', getimages)
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
  if ( document.getElementById("dateUserInput").innerHTML /*reset everytime theres a new input*/ ){
    counter = 0
  }
});
```

Every time the button gets clicked the counter increments (`counter++`).
And I want the counter to reset every time the text changes in `#dateUserInput` input.

What's the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the event listener **outside** of your button click. And use the `"input"` Event for your `#dateUserInput` element:

```js
let counter = 0

const elButton = document.getElementById("updatePic");
const elInput = document.getElementById("dateUserInput"); 

elButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  getimages();
  counter += 1;
});

elInput.addEventListener("input", () => {
  counter = 0; // reset counter
});
```